# Convert File[] to String[] in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, selenium

i have this code

```
File folder = new File("F:\\gals");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

this code returns an array of locations of all files in folder F:\gals , and i tried to use this location in selenium code

```
driver.findElement(By.id(id1)).sendKeys(listOfFiles[1]);
```

and i see errors

```
The method sendKeys(CharSequence...) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (File)
```

so i think i have to convert listOfFiles[] to String array, plz tell me simple way to do this. Thanks

Comment: what do you want to send to Selenium? Path of the file or the file content? listOfFiles[] --> String[] is unclear till we know what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to upload file, to upload file i have to send filepath

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to convert the whole array. Just call `File`'s `getAbsolutePath()` method:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(id1)).sendKeys(listOfFiles[1].getAbsolutePath());
```

But if you do want to convert the whole array, here is the **Java 8** way to do this (simplified by @RemigiusStalder):

```
String listOfPaths[] = Arrays.stream(listOfFiles).map(File::getAbsolutePath)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Java8 code could be simplified to: `String listOfPaths[] = Arrays.stream(listOfFiles).map(File::getAbsolutePath).toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 7):

Just call `File.list()` instead.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula So will `listFiles()`. The only difference is in what datatype is returned.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula I can only suggest you keep reading: ['an array of File objects is returned, one for each file *or directory* in the directory'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) [emphasis added].

Answer (score 3):

I think, you don't need to convert File[] to String[]

Just use your file array this way:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(id1)).sendKeys(listOfFiles[1].getName());
```

or, if you would like to send full file path:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(id1)).sendKeys(listOfFiles[1].getPath());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the names:

```
String [] fileNames new String[listOfFiles.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    fileNames[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
}
```

If you need full path:

```
String [] fileNames new String[listOfFiles.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    fileNames[i] = listOfFiles[i].getPath();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way: this is just a static helper method to convert File array to String array:

```
 private static String[] convertFromFilesArray(File[] files){
        String[] result = new String[files.length];
        for (int i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
            result[i] = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you try this?

```
driver.findElement(By.id(id1)).sendKeys(listOfFiles[1].getName());
```